# Adjust a jQuery Counter so the count text is hidden if the TextBox is empty

Tags: jquery

I'm using the counter below but need to adjust it so that the "0 Characters (1000 Max)" counter text is hidden if the count is 0.

```
    /*
   jQuery (character and word) counter
   Copyright (C) 2009  Wilkins Fernandez

   This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
   the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
   (at your option) any later version.

   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
   GNU General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
   along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        counter: function(options) {
            // Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings
            var defaults = {
                type: 'char',   // {char || word}
                count: 'down',  // count {up || down} from or to the goal number
                goal: 140       // count {to || from} this number                
            };
            var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            var flag = false;   // Set to true when goal is reached

            // Loop through each instance of the object that being is passed (the users selector).
            // Allows for multiple instances of the jQuery methods available to THIS (instance of the) object
            // (you can use this plug-in more than once on a page).
            return this.each(function() {
                var msg;
                var $obj = $(this);

                // Sets the appropriate message based on the options
                function get_msg_equation(objLength) {
                    // Make sure that the right values are set
                    if (typeof options.type !== 'string') {
                    } else {
                        switch (options.type) {
                            case 'char':
                                if (options.count === 'down') {
                                    msg = " character(s) left";
                                    return (options.goal - objLength);
                                }
                                else if (options.count === 'up') {
                                    msg = " characters (" + options.goal + " max)";
                                    return objLength;
                                }
                                break;
                            case 'word':
                                if (options.count === 'down') {
                                    msg = " word(s) left";
                                    return (options.goal - objLength);
                                }
                                else if (options.count === 'up') {
                                    msg = " words (" + options.goal + " max)";
                                    return objLength;
                                }
                                break;
                               default:
                        } //END switch
                    } // END if
                } // END function

                // * Initialize *: the bind event needs an object to bind to
                $('<div style="color:#CCCCCC;" id=\"' + this.id + '_counter\"><span>' + get_msg_equation($($obj).val().length ) + '</span>' + msg + '</div>').insertAfter($obj);

                // Cache the counter selector
                var $currentCount = $("#" + this.id + "_counter" + " span");

                // Bind events to a function that returns the length
                // of the characters || words in the given text field.
                $obj.bind('keyup click blur focus change paste', function(new_length) {
                    // Update characters depending on the option selected
                    switch (options.type) {
                        case 'char':
                            new_length = $($obj).val().length;
                            break;
                        case 'word':
                            if ($obj.val() === '') {
                                new_length = 0;
                            }
                            else {
                                new_length = $.trim($obj.val())
                                    .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
                                    .split(' ').length;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                    } // END switch

                    // Set flag TRUE when counter reaches goal
                    switch (options.count) {
                        case 'up':
                            if (get_msg_equation(new_length) >= options.goal && options.type === 'char') {
                                $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, options.goal));
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            if (get_msg_equation(new_length) === options.goal && options.type === 'word') {
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            } else if (get_msg_equation(new_length) > options.goal && options.type === 'word') {
                                $(this).val("");
                                $currentCount.text("0");
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'down':
                            if (get_msg_equation(new_length) <= 0 && options.type === 'char') {
                                $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, options.goal));
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            if (get_msg_equation(new_length) === 0 && options.type === 'word') {
                                flag = true;
                            } else if (get_msg_equation(new_length) < 0 && options.type === 'word') {
                                $(this).val("");
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                    } // END switch

                    // Listen on keydown to catch the last character or word typed
                    // and prevent the user from typing
                    $obj.keydown(function(event) {
                        if (flag) {
                            this.focus();
                            // Listen for delete & backspace
                            if ((event.keyCode !== 46 && event.keyCode !== 8)) {
                                if ($(this).val().length > options.goal && options.type === 'char') {
                                    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, options.goal));
                                    return false;   // Stop the default action (typing)
                                    // Listen for blank (spacebar) & return 
                                } else if (event.keyCode !== 32 && event.keyCode !== 8 && options.type === 'word') {   //Allow to continue typing last word
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    return false;   // Stop the default action (typing)
                                }
                            } else {
                                flag = false;
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }); // END keydown
                    $currentCount.text(get_msg_equation(new_length));
                }); // END Bind
            }); //END return
        } // END counter function
    }); // END extend
}) // END function
(jQuery); // Return jQuery object
```

Comment: maybe use http://www.jsfiddle.net kind of hard to understand all that code...

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for a response from someone who knows jQuery.

Comment: I understand jquery, It's just a very very long code which would be better with a live demo easily done in jsfiddle

Comment: I plugged it into jsfiddle.net and got nothing. ?

Comment: you'll want to share that code with us so we can then help... :)

Answer (score 0):

This quite works

http://jsfiddle.net/Shac4/

You just need to hide the counter on the first pass

Comment: I see. My web form has 15 of the TextBoxes that use the counter and the first thing I do when the page loads is to hide the TextBoxes with JavaScript and provide a little button to show the TextBox if it's needed. So, all the TextBoxes start out hidden, but the text, "0 Characters (1000 Max)" still shows.  I'm not sure how to hide the counter on the first pass.

Comment: I plugged your modification into my form and it works well once a TextBox is "opened" or unhidden and then hidden again.  I can live with it like this, but it would be perfect if all the count texts started out hidden and then showed if text was entered into the TextBox.  I'll be out of the office on the long weekend, so I hope you have a good weekend.  I'll pop in tomorrow if I get a chance to work on this, but I won't be in the office tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the modification to the jquery.counter-1.0.js you provided I made this change so that the default state of the counter text is hidden and only shows if text is typed into the Textbox.

At around line 62 I added "display:none;" to the div style:

```
// * Initialize *: the bind event needs an object to bind to
$('<div style="color:#CCCCCC; display:none;" id=\"' + this.id + '_counter\"><span>' + get_msg_equation($($obj).val().length) + '</span>' + msg + '</div>').insertAfter($obj);
// Cache the counter selector
var $currentCount = $("#" + this.id + "_counter" + " span");
```